# name = f'scheduler-test-{stage}' SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, format

I get a syntax error on my code below. Could you help me resolve it?

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import sys
import boto3
client = boto3.client('sns')
if __name__ == '__main__':

  if len(sys.argv) < 2:
     print('Missing argument for stage.')
     exit()
  stage = sys.argv[1]

  name = f'scheduler-test-{stage}'
  print(f'Creating topic {name}')
  create_response = client.create_topic(Name=name,)
  arn = create_response['TopicArn']
  print(f'Created topic {name} with arn {arn}')
  if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        role = sys.argv[2]
  else:
        role = 'arn:aws:sts::256608350746:assumed-role/aws-scheduler-prod-us-east-1-lambdaRole/aws-scheduler-prod-emitter'
  print(f'Granting publish rights to {name} topic for role {role}')

  permission_response = client.add_permission(
        TopicArn=arn,
        Label=f'{name}-publish-access',
        AWSAccountId=[str(role)],
        ActionName=['Publish']
  )
  print('Done')
```

I am getting below error

File "./init_output_topic.py", line 18
name = f'scheduler-test-{stage}'
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running a python 3+ syntax with python 2. String formatting using the "f" was introduced at python 3.

If you want to use python 2 you need to use the old formatting:

```
name = 'scheduler-test-%s' % (stage)
```

https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Or just compile the code using "python3 script.py"

Comment: It's worth noting that f-strings weren't added until python 3.6. The shebang does indicate it should run with python3, but evidently a version of python older than 3.6 is installed.